# Automated statistics gathering from C# applications

Tags: c#, statistics, web-statistics

I have made a C# application , now I want to create **custom survey** (actually sending data **automatically** to me, about - **crashes , usage duration** etc.) to enhance my application .

How can I do it ?

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you. Also there is way too little information

Comment: My apologies at first , for not providing proper information . Actually I didn't asked for code . Let's assume I have an app , text editor , which has auto-complete enabled . Now how many times user uses that feature I have saved in a local file , xml , database or so and so . Actually what I want is I want to upload those data to my server(own) periodically . How can I do it . I have no idea . Can you help now ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this:

1. Host a REST service at your server, the common way is to add a WebAPI controller in ASP.NET MVC project.
2. On the client application create a `System.Threading.Timer` instance and set desired schedule to send the statistics. Or just send them each time user starts your application.
3. Send statistics to your REST service using `WebClient/HttpClient`.

Tutorials:

[Get Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

[Call a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Thanks . Any suggested tutorial will be very helpful . Thanks again .

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad I added a few links to my post, they can help you to setup WebAPI and call it from client app

Comment: thanks a lot . these means a lot to me . gratitude .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the rough reception you received with that one comment.  Many of us understood you weren't asking for us to write code for you, and I think you had a legit question.

You might want to also look at the .Net Trace capabilities.  While you won't get data sent to you **automatically**, there's a built-in, easy-to-use framework that's unobtrusive and let's you gather statistics.  Here are some links to check out:

[The Trace Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[How to Add Trace Statements to Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-add-trace-statements-to-application-code?view=netframework-4.7.2)

See also

[Trace Listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/trace-listeners)

So there you go.  Another possible way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I had no idea about this "Trace class" , still I have no idea about it . I am studying . As my study will be done , I will let you know . In between if any problem arises maybe I will bother you again , unless I find a stackoverflow thread .Thanks .

Comment: No worries Maifee.  Another approach you might want to investigate is using MSMQ in C#.  It's a relatively easy to use send/receive message queuing system with tons of easy to understand C# examples available.  Any approach you take, you'll have some homework and coding to do, that's the intent I saw in your question.  You asked for starting points.  However you approach this, with opwix's excellent answer or the ideas I'm throwing out, you're looking at a framework where you build a listener and then the capability to easily send messages to it from your app.  Many possibilities.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling your own, which would require a lot of work to set up a server to gather the metrics and produce reports, 3rd party services exist which provide comprehensive end-to-end solutions for app metrics and exception reporting. I've worked with [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/). They are built for large and complex backend systems but it's worked well for me in the context of a small C# WPF desktop app. It was only about ten lines of code to [get started](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/wpf/). For example this will get exception reporting up and running:

```cs
using System.Windows;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        SentrySdk.Init(o =>
        {
            // Tells which project in Sentry to send events to:
            o.Dsn = "https://example.ingest.sentry.io/x";
          
            // Enable Global Mode since this is a client app
            o.IsGlobalModeEnabled = true;
        });
        DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureException(e.Exception);

        // If you want to avoid the application from crashing:
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I believe [mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) and [rollbar](https://rollbar.com/) offer something similar.